# Listening to onKeyDown event when my application is not in foreground(It is in onPause)

Tags: android

Is there any way to Listen to onKeyDown event when my application is not in foreground(It is in onPause).

Comment: What you have search for this.

Comment: I know that I can do it while my app is in foreground but i did not find any way to do it when my app is in onPause

Comment: If your activity is in onPause then it means that it is in back ground, some other activity is in forGround may be it is home screen or any application activity.

Comment: That I know dude. Is that still possible to listen to keyevents?

Comment: I know this is an old question but did anyone found a way?